# How to disable accessibility for a view including all it's subviews?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, accessibility, voiceover

When I set `isAccessibilityElement = NO` on a view that contains subviews with `isAccessibilityElement = YES`, VoiceOver still detects them.

I need to switch off accessibility for an entire view hierarchy that must be handled differently by VoiceOver. How can I achieve this without having to loop through every single item in the object graph and mess with it's setting?

Answer (score 35):

`self.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;`

This makes all subviews hidden from accessibility.

Answer (score 10):

I would try setting the `accessibilityElementsHidden` property of the main view to YES. If that does not what you want, I would try overriding the `UIAccessibilityContainer` methods on the main view to return 0 children.

Answer (score 4):

Just set the accessibilityElementsHidden property.