# Disable VoiceOver on a MapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, accessibility, voiceover

I have a view controller where there is a MKMapView, and I want to disable Voiceover focus on this item. I tried this

```
[self.map setAccessibilityContainerType:UIAccessibilityContainerTypeNone];
```

but have the following warning :

> 'setAccessibilityContainerType:' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer

When testing, VoiceOver focuses on the items which are present on the map, like towns or province borders and I don't know how to ignore these items

**EDIT**: i've tried the following answer:

[How to disable accessibility for a view including all it's subviews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897392/how-to-disable-accessibility-for-a-view-including-all-its-subviews)

so it's now

```
  self.map.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;
```

And it works great !!

Comment: try self.map.isAccessibilleElement = NO;

Comment: I've tried this way but it wasn't successful.

self.map.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES; works fine for me :)